# Call a method from parent class

Tags: php

I am really going crazy with this problem.
I am not able to call a method from the parent class in a static method of a child class..

This is what I tried but it does not work..

```
class custom extends service {

    private $service;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->service = new service;
    }

   public static function activematches($callback) {

        $select_by_user = parent::$db->select('matches', '*', array('user_id' => $user_id, 

        if (count($select_by_user) == 0 && count($select_by_opponent) == 0)
            parent::$check->send('11');
        else
            $this->service->make($callback['request'], $callback['data']);
    }
```

When I call `$this->service` I get:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
```

I tried making that as static, I tried putting the same method in the child class by calling the parent method parent::method, but nothing...

I am new to OOP, any help?

Comment: You are using `$this` in a static function, that's wrong because it maybe called statically or in an object context.

Comment: @vicentazo thanks for telling me something I already know...

Comment: Aren't the parentheses missing in here? `$this->service = new service();`

Comment: @MurifoX: They are optional.

Comment: @DiegoPucci: Well, that's what's causing your issue.

Answer (score 3):

For access within a static invocation the property must be defined static as well

```
 protected static $services;
```

From there you need to reference within your static methos as either.

```
 self::$services
```

or

```
 static::$services
```

Referencing `self` in this context will refer to $services property where the reference is defined. `static` will reference the property from the class context that the reference was invoked on. For more information see what the manual has to say about [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

**UPDATE**

Based on the fact that `custom` extends `service` in this case I doubt this is what you are really after. A class definition like :

```
class custom extends service {
    public function activematches($callback, $user_id) {

        $select_by_user = $this->db->select('matches', '*', array('user_id' => $user_id)); 
        if (count($select_by_user) == 0 && count($select_by_opponent) == 0)
            $this->check->send('11');
        else
            $this->make($callback['request'], $callback['data']);
    }
}
```

May be closer to what you want.

Comment: Now I am getting Fatal error: Call to a member function make() on a non-object

Comment: @diegopucci The assignment in your constructor also has to use this notation.

Comment: I didn't know you could use `static::`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat static is for [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Comment: This is what I am doing..but nothing.. How do I call a public method of a parent class inside a static method of a child class? Maybe this question is clearer

Comment: This is what I am doing..but nothing.. How do I call a public method of a parent class inside a static method of a child class? Maybe this question is clearer

Comment: I don't think u understand OOP at all.. When u inherit a class, u inherit its methods and fields which are public or protected

Comment: @DiegoPucci by using parent::method() but for the call to be static the invokation of the caller also has to be static.  You may also be able to force it static by explictily naming the parent `MyParentClass::staticMethod()`

Comment: @Darkbee good observation... I didn't notice that this custom extended service.

Comment: @Orangepill comment was meant for OP, not u c-:

Comment: @Darkbee I know... but I think you identified the underlying issue the OP is having and it is not what he is asking.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent method, `make` is not static:
You *can't* call a non-static method from the parent class from a static method of the child class. Have you considered making the child method not-static? I think that's your best option here.

If the parent method `make` is static:

```
parent::make($callback['request'], $callback['data']);
```

But this is called [Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) which was introduced in PHP 5.3.0. It won't work in older versions, so be careful with that.

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

This is actually answer for your question. The specific of [static members of class](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php) is - you can use them without making an object. $this - reference for object, in which context method was called.

So try to look on problem in this way - in static member you don't have any $this.
You can only use static members of parent class in this way - self::method.

Or, you can actually create an object on parent class and use any "dynamic" method in "dynamic" notation, but this will make you even more crazy later, believe me)